# Code merging & release management strategies for handling multiple vendors, multiple feature sets, staggered release dates, same codebase

Tags: merge, release-management

My question is about code merging and release management strategies that minimise 'code merge pain' when you have dinstinct vendors working on distinct feature sets with distinct release dates but all working on the same codebase. Adapted from a real world situation..

Let's say you have a production web application, and the code base for this system is in a code repository (in this case GIT).

Your company decides to kick off three projects at the same time, each project will work on a new set of features for the web application (feature set 1, feature set 2, feature set 3). These are fairly big feature sets and a lot of code will be written. The company brings in three different vendors to work on each feature set. The vendors are not co-located. Some of the vendors will be on site, some will work remotely. As stated, each feature set has a different release date, to be staggered over a few months.

The project kicks off and each vendor branches off a copy of the code base from the main line in GIT in to their own development line (dev line 1, dev line 2, dev line 3), and each vendor begins working on their own feature set, checking changes back in to their distinct development line as they go.

In the meantime, there's an occasional 'BAU' prod release that changes the Production codebase of the web application. Whenever this happens, the release manager notifies each vendor to ensure they each 'pull down and merge' from the main line, in to their distinct dev lines.

I'm looking for strategies to minimise "code merge pain" when merging code between the projects, ie, when code from one project is merged with code from another project.

Merge early and often you say? That's a great strategy when you have a single development team working on features that you know will all be released together. I'm struggling to see how you can 'merge early and often' when the feature sets are being worked on by distinct development teams, and have different release dates for their respective feature sets.

One strategy would be to do absolutely no code merging between the three distinct development lines until one of the feature sets has been released to production. At that point, the two remaining active development lines would 'pull down and merge' from the main line as per normal process. The risk here is of course, it could be many months of parallel development before such a code merge can happen.

As stated, vendors are not co-located nor even part of the same development team. There will be some opportunities for communication between the distinct dev teams but not a huge amount. I think this makes the use of [Feature Toggles](http://martinfowler.com/articles/feature-toggles.html) somewhat impractical for helping to minimise the pain.

Any advice welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Are the features backwards and mutually compatible ?

Comment: The 3 x feature sets are reasonably distinct from each other - certainly the vast bulk of code written as part each dev line will be distinct from the other dev lines. However, there will be some overlap, and we certainly intend to regression test any time there's a merge back in to the main line to prepare a release candidate.